# Scrollable plugIn questions with jQuery Tools

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-tools

I am using this plugin with one pane being shown at a time and I have those little circles on top to navigate through each pane.

If I have three panes within my carousel, so therefore against each of these little circle buttons, it assigns 0, 1 and 2 as href values, how can I get access to these href index values when I click on each of these circles?

I basically would like to capture the pane href value I am currently on when clicked but I don't know how to do this or locate onClick event within plugin.

See: http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example you given above just use:

```
$('div.navi > a').click(function () {
    console.log($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Comment: probably inside of `$(document).ready` callback function after initializing the scrollable component

Comment: Just placed your code there and when I click on the circle, nothing appeared. How can I get the href value to display on the screen as I click on a circle button to see if the correct result is displayed?